# How do you limit the x axes of a histogram in R and zoom in on data?

Tags: r

How would I limit the x axes in R?
The x axis are dates, e.g. Dec 15, Dec 16, Dec 17.

Comment: please provide a set of reproducible data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hist(as.Date(rnorm(10000, 18000, 300), origin='1970-01-01'), 
     breaks = 1000, 
     xlim = c(as.Date('2018-08-01'), as.Date('2018-09-01')))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to change the incrementing values of the times on the x axis?

Comment: You could also try xlim=as.Date(c("2012-03-09", "2016-08-30")). It sounds like the granularity of your data is daily(?), in which case working with POSIXcts is overkill.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @DavveK! I think the problem statement has been edited again, so I reverted the answer to a previous version